# Sun object not moving when Rendering Animation

Tags: python, animation, eevee-render-engine

I've problem Rendering sun rotation animation. Steps to reproduce:

1. Create the sun object
2. Set 1st keyframe

   - Select keyframe
   - Rotate sun object using the handle
   - "I" > Select Rotation
3. Set 10th keyframe (Reproduce same steps found in 2nd point)
4. Add `frame_change_post` handler to print sun `rotation_euler`
5. Run Render > Render Animation

The result was 11 times (0-10) printed same rotation Euler
`<Euler (x=-7.9113, y=0.2392, z=-7.1615), order='XYZ'>`  .But when I move from keyframe to keyframe Euler XYZ positions are updated. Why is that so?

Here is a demo plugin created to replicate the issue:

```
bl_info = {
"name": "Sun animation using lever",
"author": "karlisup",
"version": (1, 0),
"blender": (2, 80, 0),
}
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

@persistent
def sun_handler(scene, depsgraph):
    if "Sun" not in bpy.data.objects:
        create_sun()
    sun = bpy.data.objects["Sun"]
    print(scene.frame_current, sun.rotation_euler)

def create_sun():
    bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection
    light_data = bpy.data.lights.new(name="Sun", type='SUN')
    light_data.energy = 30
    light_object = bpy.data.objects.new(name="Sun", object_data=light_data)
    light_object.location = (5, 5, 5)
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(light_object)
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = light_object

def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(sun_handler)

def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.remove(sun_handler)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: To me, this script is working correctly except that the handler should have 2 arguments: the scene and the depsgraph. To tell it another way, I don't think what is printed is from the function indicated in the question.

Comment: Seen your edit. What I meant was not only about the missing arguments but the hypothesis that all works fine (it works fine when I test it) but these missing arguments or something else make so what is printed is your env is not the rotation of the expected object.

Comment: Thanks, @lemon for the comment. I updated the code regarding handler parameters. I'll try to clarify my question as this doesn't quite solve my confusion. The problem is with 2 views. In one Euler changes sun rotation coordinates, but whenever Animation is Rendered - it doesn't. I tried to illustrate it here: https://youtu.be/0Q8FsuDrC1k I

Comment: You say that I should be somehow extracting rotation of an object from the scene (the context)? Sorry, Blender is new to me :)

Comment: "what is printed is your env is not the rotation of the expected object" This totally makes sense. Could you help me to understand how to get a rotation of the object while I am using "Render Animation" as I couldn't find examples in existing atmosphere plugins?

Comment: ok... did not understand at first. My hypothesis was wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that during rendering you need to use the depsgraph so that you obtain an evaluated object.

Don't know why this is not useful when just playing the animation.

So add this line:

```
sun = sun.evaluated_get(depsgraph)
```

In the complete function:

```
@persistent
def sun_handler(scene, depsgraph):
    if "Sun" not in bpy.data.objects:
        create_sun()
    sun = bpy.data.objects["Sun"]
    sun = sun.evaluated_get(depsgraph)
    print(scene.frame_current, sun.rotation_euler)
```

A link to the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Depsgraph.html) if needed.

For information, I've asked on blender coders and had an answer by *dr.Sybren*:

> The difference is caused by the render engine using its own dependency
> graph, which is not marked as 'active'. As a result, it does not copy
> animated values back from evaluated to original objects.

This behavior is confirmed to be intended.

Comment: Note that the [depsgraph argument for the handler](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.81/Python_API#Handlers) only exists since 2.81.

Comment: I tested the demo script and it really worked, awesome! I still got to wrap my head around about "why" and "how" yet. Just let me first test it on the real plugin, just to see if it works there.

Comment: Although it introduced another issue that I've to fix, it solved the issue I was tackling for a while. Thank you for your effort! I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In sequence-view:

- click *View* menu item
- click *Sequence Render animation*

This will correctly export an animation with frame_handler