# Blender Only Rendering Frame Displayed in UI When . blend Last Saved

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to render a video of two moving fibers. After applying an emitter to the fibers meshes and applying the constraint copy transform to the emitter I am able to see the emitter moving in sync with the fiber mesh, but when I save the file the emitter freezes on the current frame in the UI and the animation output.

For context I'm running version 2.79 of Blender, I am using a render farm, but I don't think that's the issue since I see freezing in the .blend file, and the .blend file is on cycles render.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks
(Also put the hair emitter script below)

````
import bpy
import math
import mathutils
import os
import threading
import time
import logging
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

# Tested with Blender 2.66

# File configuration
meshName = "hair"
emitterMeshName = "hair-emitter"
shouldRemoveOldMesh = True

# Hair configuration
useBSplineInterpolation = True
numberOfSegmentsToDrawForPreview = 10
numberOfSegmentsToRender = 12
hairShape = -0.4
hairWidth = 0.7

def RemoveOldMesh(theMeshName):
    candidateList = [item.name for item in bpy.data.objects]
 
    for name in candidateList:
        bpy.data.objects[name].select = (name == theMeshName)
    
    bpy.ops.object.delete()

def BuildVertex2EdgeMap(theMesh):
    vertex2EdgeMap = [-1] * len(theMesh.data.vertices)
    
    for edge in theMesh.data.edges:
        vertex2EdgeMap[edge.vertices[0]] = edge.index
        
    return vertex2EdgeMap

def BuildStrand(theMesh, theVertex2EdgeMap, theStartVertexIndex):
    strand = []
    maximumNumberOfSegments = 1000

    currentVertex = theMesh.data.vertices[theStartVertexIndex]
    strand.append(currentVertex.index)
    
    for i in range(maximumNumberOfSegments):
        currentEdgeIndex = theVertex2EdgeMap[currentVertex.index]
        
        if currentEdgeIndex == -1:
            break
        
        currentEdge = theMesh.data.edges[currentEdgeIndex]
        
        currentVertex = theMesh.data.vertices[currentEdge.vertices[1]]
        strand.append(currentVertex.index)
        
    return strand

def BuildStrands(theMesh, theVertex2EdgeMap):
    strands = []
    currentStartVertexIndex = 0
    maximumNumberOfStrands = 100000
    
    for i in range(maximumNumberOfStrands):
        if currentStartVertexIndex >= len(theMesh.data.vertices):
            break
        
        strand = BuildStrand(theMesh, theVertex2EdgeMap, currentStartVertexIndex)
        strands.append(strand)
        
        currentStartVertexIndex = strand[-1] + 1
    
    return strands

def CreateEmitterMesh(theMesh):
    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(emitterMeshName)
    mesh.from_pydata([(0, 0, 0)], [], [])
    mesh.update()
    
    object = bpy.data.objects.new(emitterMeshName, mesh)
    object.data = mesh
    object.rotation_euler = mathutils.Euler((0.5 * math.pi, 0, 0))
    
    scene = bpy.context.scene
    scene.objects.link(object)
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = object
    
    bpy.ops.object.constraint_add(type = "COPY_TRANSFORMS")
    object.constraints[0].target = theMesh
    
    return object

def HideMesh(theMesh):
    theMesh.hide = True
    theMesh.hide_render = True

def SubSampleStrandSegments(theStrands):
    strands = []
    maximumNumberOfSegments = 51
    
    for strand in theStrands:
        if len(strand) > maximumNumberOfSegments:
            strands.append(strand[0::math.ceil(len(strand)/maximumNumberOfSegments)])
        else:
            strands.append(strand)
        
    return strands

def SortStrands(theStrands):
    sortedStrands = []
    
    strandSegments = sorted([len(strand) for strand in theStrands])
    numberOfSegmentsForSystems = sorted(list(set(strandSegments)))
    
    for numberOfSegments in numberOfSegmentsForSystems:
        sortedStrands.append([strand for strand in theStrands if len(strand) == numberOfSegments])

    return sortedStrands

def CreateParticleSystem(theEmitMesh, theNumberOfParticles, theNumberOfSegments):
    bpy.ops.object.particle_system_add()
    particleSystem = theEmitMesh.particle_systems.active
    particleSystem.name = "hair"
    
    particleSettings = particleSystem.settings
    particleSettings.name = "hair-settings"
    particleSettings.type = "HAIR"
    particleSettings.count = theNumberOfParticles
    particleSettings.emit_from = "FACE"
    particleSettings.use_hair_bspline = useBSplineInterpolation
    particleSettings.draw_step = numberOfSegmentsToDrawForPreview
    particleSettings.render_step = numberOfSegmentsToRender
    particleSettings.hair_step = theNumberOfSegments - 1
    particleSettings.use_advanced_hair = True
    particleSettings.physics_type = "KEYED"
    
    particleSettings.cycles.shape = hairShape
    particleSettings.cycles.root_width = hairWidth
    
    return particleSystem

def CreateParticleSystems(theStrands, theEmitMesh):
    for strandsForParticleSystem in theStrands:
        numberOfParticles = len(strandsForParticleSystem)
        numberOfSegments = len(strandsForParticleSystem[0])
        
        CreateParticleSystem(theEmitMesh, numberOfParticles, numberOfSegments)

def SetParticleStrand(theStrand, theParticles, theMesh, theFrame):
    numberOfSegments = len(theStrand)
    vertices = mesh.data.shape_keys.key_blocks[theFrame - 1].data
    startCoordinates = vertices[theStrand[0]].co
    
    theParticles.location = startCoordinates
    theParticles.hair_keys[0].co = startCoordinates
    
    for i in range(numberOfSegments - 1):
        theParticles.hair_keys[i + 1].co = vertices[theStrand[i + 1]].co

def SetParticleStrands(theStrands, theParticleSystem, theMesh, theFrame, isInitialSetting):
    if isInitialSetting:
        bpy.ops.particle.particle_edit_toggle()
    
    for i in range(len(theStrands)):
        SetParticleStrand(theStrands[i], theParticleSystem.particles[i], theMesh, theFrame)

    if isInitialSetting:
        bpy.ops.particle.particle_edit_toggle()

def SetStrandsForParticleSystems(theMesh, theEmitMesh, theFrame, isInitialSetting):
    theStrands = theEmitMesh["strands"]
    
    for i in range(len(theStrands)):
        SetParticleStrands(theStrands[i], theEmitMesh.particle_systems[i], theMesh, theFrame, isInitialSetting)

def SaveParticleStrands(theStrands, theEmitMesh):
    theEmitMesh["strands"] = theStrands

@persistent
def UpdateParticleSystem(scene):
    global mesh, emitterMesh
    
    oldMesh = bpy.context.scene.objects.active
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = emitterMesh
    
    start = scene.frame_start
    end = scene.frame_end
    current = max(start, min(scene.frame_current, end))
    
    SetStrandsForParticleSystems(mesh, emitterMesh, current, False)
    
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = oldMesh

def SetFrameHandlers(theUpdateMethod):
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.clear()
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(theUpdateMethod)
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.clear()
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(theUpdateMethod)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Remove possibly existing old mesh
    if shouldRemoveOldMesh:
        RemoveOldMesh(emitterMeshName);
    
    mesh = bpy.context.scene.objects[meshName]
    
    # Calculate strand segments
    vertex2EdgeMap = BuildVertex2EdgeMap(mesh)
    strands = BuildStrands(mesh, vertex2EdgeMap)
    
    # Subsample strand segments
    strands = SubSampleStrandSegments(strands)
    strands = SortStrands(strands)
    
    # Create dummy emitter and particle system
    emitterMesh = CreateEmitterMesh(mesh)
    HideMesh(mesh)
    
    # Create particle systems
    CreateParticleSystems(strands, emitterMesh)
    
    # Save strands into emitter mesh
    SaveParticleStrands(strands, emitterMesh)
    
    # Set current strands
    start = bpy.context.scene.frame_start
    end = bpy.context.scene.frame_end
    current = max(start, min(bpy.context.scene.frame_current, end))
    SetStrandsForParticleSystems(mesh, emitterMesh, current, True)
    
    # Set frame handlers
    SetFrameHandlers(UpdateParticleSystem)
else:
    # Get existing meshes
    mesh = bpy.context.scene.objects[meshName]
    emitterMesh = bpy.context.scene.objects[emitterMeshName]
    
    # Set frame handlers
    SetFrameHandlers(UpdateParticleSystem)
```
````

Comment: I don't have 2.79 anymore. However, sounds like there is something wrong with the handlers. Try to remove `bpy.app.handlers.*` in `SetFrameHandlers()` one by one and see if the error persists. Also have a look into the console, as of Blender 2.79b or something they changed the arguments for handlers... https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/167899/31447

Comment: @brockmann it looks like i'm still having the same problem

Comment: Downloaded blender 2.79, renamed the cube to 'hair', added a particle system called 'hair-emitter' and I still get quite a bunch of errors. What else is required to set that up?